# Javascript - Generic Object Function

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

Ok so my question is how to setup a generic function inside of a Javascript object using the constructor pattern that will take the object instance's data as parameters?

For instance:

```
function ObjTest() = {
    this.obA = 0;
    this.obA_Inc = 1;
    this.obA_Max = 10;

    this.Up_Value = function(ob, obI, obM) {
        if(ob <= obM) {
            ob += obI;

            if(ob > obM) {
                ob = obM;
            }
        }
    }
}

var obj = new ObjTest();
obj.Up_Value(obj.obA, obj.obA_Inc, obj.obA_Max)
```

If there is a better way to work with Javascript objects, that would allow for instances like this, I would love to hear about that pattern.

Comment: Why would you take them as parameters if they’re already on the object? `if (this.obA < this.obA_Max)`, etc..

Comment: I second @Ryan, I was about to write the same... it makes little sense.

Comment: sidenote: `ob = Math.min(ob + obI, obM)` sums up the logic in your function

Comment: I'll be creating instances of the object outside of the function itself. And there will be multiple pieces of data in it, not just obA, but also obB, obC, etc. I want a generic function that I can pass which set of data I'm working with for that specific object and perform the same functionality on each set without having to write it all out for each set of data. This was just a simple example to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're talking about these "sets of data", this screams object to me.

*Don't use prefixed or enumerated properties to indicate that they belong together. Use a proper Object or an Array. In this case, something like `this.objA = {value: 0, inc: 1, max: 10}`.*

And if this function always operates on one of these objects, and doesn't seem to have any other relationship to `ObjTest`, then maybe it's not a method of `ObjTest`, but instead a method of these objects. And would be better off on them.

```js
//So, as these objects have logic, let's use a class
class ValueObj {
  constructor(value, inc, max) {
    this.value = value;
    this.inc = inc;
    this.max = max;
  }

  Up_Value() {
    this.value = Math.min(this.value + this.inc, this.max);
  }
}

function ObjTest() {
  this.objA = new ValueObj(0, 1, 10);
  this.objB = new ValueObj(0, 2, 15);
}

var obj = new ObjTest();
//and since you call the method on the object itself, 
//you don't need to pass anything to the function
console.log("before", JSON.stringify(obj,null,2));
obj.objA.Up_Value();
console.log("after", JSON.stringify(obj,null,2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

*you can use `console.log(obj);` but in your browser console this won't show the correct "before" state. That's why I use `JSON.stringify()` in the code.*

Comment: Ok so I tried using class but it keeps giving me an error on the first quote mark saying ";" expected. I've looked at some class tutorials for JS and they all say the same thing and give the same error.... What am I missing?

Comment: @JoshC. Go and learn on [class - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class)

Comment: @JoshC. No, JS doesn't have that kind of classes. This is just syntactic sugar on top of its prototypal inheritance model *(It looks cleaner)*. I've changed the code block into a runable snippet. But to tell you why you get an error, you'd have to post the code that throws this error.

Comment: The code that I get an error for is:
class obj { }
The error shows at the first bracket stating ";" expected.
Even when I add a constructor or anything else it still states this.

But it's fine, I just converted what you said into the constructor pattern. Now it all works fine.